# Beautify pandas display dataframe to one line per column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here's my data, I want to do make this dataframe have one column per entry in display. I know it seems easy, maybe just one line code, but I can't find by searching on google and read from [pandas option](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/options.html)

```
   id   id_text     id_sales            id_sales_text
    0   [17,        aee9ddd8-           [17, 230, 214,
        230,        d61b-11e6-          19, 43, 196, 4, 
        214,        b240-000d3aa19209   90, 178, 64, 0,... 
        27,
        174,
        233,
        221,
        216,
        178,
        64...
    1   [17,        3b68a435           [17, 230, 214, 
        230,        d61d-11e6-         19, 43, 196, 4, 
        214,        b240-              90, 178, 64, 0,...
        29,         000d3aa19209 
        59,
        104,
        164,
        53,
        178,
        64,
        ...
```

What I want is

```
id  id_text                                             id_sales
0   [17, 230, 214, 27, 174, 233, 221, 216, 178, 64...   aee9ddd8-d61b-11e6-b240-000d3aa19209    [17, 230, 214, 19, 43, 196, 4, 90, 178, 64, 0,...
1   [17, 230, 214, 29, 59, 104, 164, 53, 178, 64, ...   3b68a435-d61d-11e6-b240-000d3aa19209    [17, 230, 214, 19, 43, 196, 4, 90, 178, 64, 0,..
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried

```
pd.set_option('expand_frame_repr', False)
```

or you can try

```
pd.set_option('max_colwidth', 100)
```

['max_colwidth'](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.set_option.html) is the maximum width in characters of a column in the repr of a pandas data structure. When the column overflows, a ”...” placeholder is embedded in the output. [default: 50]

Also take a look at [pandas.set_options](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.set_option.html#pandas-set-option)